# Problem with fitting square root-like function

Tags: fitting, warning-messages, data

I have following data:

```
data={{374.46707`, 0.665317421546049`}, {375.52396999999996`, 
   0.660664852164608`}, {376.58087`, 0.665317421546049`}, {377.63777`,
    0.651359713401726`}, {378.69467`, 
   0.651359713401726`}, {379.75156999999996`, 
   0.637402005257403`}, {380.80859999999996`, 
   0.637402005257403`}, {381.8655`, 0.609486588968758`}, {382.9224`, 
   0.600181450205876`}, {383.97929999999997`, 
   0.56761346453579`}, {385.0362`, 0.507130062577058`}, {386.0931`, 
   0.407565077814223`}, {387.15, 0}};
```

and I am fitting following function:

```
    nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, {3/4 A (1 + Sqrt[1 - (8 ((x - B)+(x - B)^2))/(9(387.15 - B))]), 0.0 < A < 0.4, 387 < B < 387.15}, {{B,387}, {A, 0.306}}, x]
```

and I get an error, from which other errors follow:

> NonlinearModelFit::nrnum: The function value -95.7402-17.0695 I is not a real number at {B,A} = {387.,0.306}.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: What does the error say?

Comment: NonlinearModelFit::nrnum: The function value -95.7402-17.0695 I is not a real number at {B,A} = {387.,0.306}.

IPOPTMinimize::badobj: Invalid objective function. The objective function doesn't evaluate to a real-valued numeric result at the initial point.

NonlinearModelFit::nrgnum: The gradient is not a vector of real numbers at {B,A} = {387.,0.306}.

Comment: The error message is telling you that you're imaginary numbers for at least some of the observations given the starting value of `B = 387`.  Also the starting value you give isn't really in the range of values for which you've restricted `B`.  I would remove the restriction on `B` and use 395 as the starting value.

Answer (score 3):

FindFit gives a quite good approximation!
Try a fit function which vanishs for `x=387.15`

```
fit = FindFit[data,Sqrt[ 387.15 - x] (b  + c ( 387.15 - x) )/(1 + d ( 387.15 -x)), {b, c, d}, x]
(*{b -> 0.456939, c -> 0.0116198, d -> 0.175918}*)

Show[{ListPlot[data], 
Plot[Sqrt[ 387.15 - x] (b  + c ( 387.15 - x) )/(1 + d ( 387.15 - x)) /. fit, {x, 375, 387.15}, 
PlotRange -> All]}, PlotRange -> {0, .7}]
```

[image]

Of course  NonlinearModelFit also works:

```
nmf = NonlinearModelFit[data,Sqrt[ 387.15 - x] (b  + c ( 387.15 - x) )/(1 + d ( 387.15 - x)), { b, c, d}, x];
Normal[nmf]
(*((0.456939 + 0.0116198 (387.15 - x)) Sqrt[387.15 - x])/(1 +0.175918 (387.15 - x))*)
```